# How are these postgres keywords working together?

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
insert into flushtest select x, repeat('1234567890', 100) from generate_series(2, 100) x
```

I understand insert, select, repeat, and generate_series as individual items but I am having a hard time understanding their interaction here? If someone could explain what the query is doing and how each part contributes to that, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Delete the `INSERT INTO` part and run just the `SELECT`. Break it down into smaller parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`generate_series(2, 100)` generates 99 rows, producing numbers from 2 to 100, as you can see with this query:

```
select x from generate_series(2, 100) as x;
```

Next, `repeat('1234567890', 100)` adds an additional column to this result set, in each its row generating a string having 100 repeated `'1234567890'`, see

```
select x, repeat('1234567890', 100) from generate_series(2, 100) x;
```

Finally, `insert into flushtest` takes that result set (which as I've said, has 99 rows and 2 columns) and inserts it to `flushtest` table.